# Error in the presentation of the Data time in the excel sheet

Tags: excel, vba

I have a program that has a CopyToBook method that reads the data from an array final_list (i) and presents them in a spreadsheet called "Data" to the user.
But the problem is that when the date 01/04/2017 it presents me on the screen the date exchanged between the month and the day.
What could be happening?
I have already debugged and the program shows the correct values, just shows wrong in the spreadsheet.

> 

```
Public Sub copy_to_book()

Dim i As Integer
Dim a As Integer





      'adiciona uma nova folha de calculo a seguir a ultima
        ThisWorkbook.Activate


 Worksheets.Add After:=ActiveSheet  ' :=  é usado para atribuir um valor a um determinado argumento nom

eado  apenas dentro de um método ou função.


        'Muda o nome a folha de calculo criada  para o nome da torneira

        ActiveSheet.Select
        ActiveSheet.Name = "DADOS"





 'Faz cabeçalho das colunas

    Worksheets("DADOS").Range("A1:F1").Value = Array("Timestamp", "Porta", "Setor", "Leitura ", "Valor", "Duração")
    Let Range("A1:F1").Interior.ColorIndex = 36

   'Adicona os dados no array na folha de calculo apartir da terceira linha
    'prenche as celulas da folha de calculo
        ' se a lista de consumos nao estiver vazia

    If (Not lista_final) <> -1 Then ' Se a lista de consumos estiver vazia ela esta igual a - 1

        For i = LBound(lista_final) To UBound(lista_final)


                Worksheets("DADOS").Range("A" & a + 2).Value = Format(lista_final(i).time1, "dd/mm/yyyy hh:mm:ss.SSS")
                Worksheets("DADOS").Range("A" & a + 3).Value = Format(lista_final(i).time1, "dd/mm/yyyy hh:mm:ss.SS

S")
                Worksheets("DADOS").Range("A" & a + 4).Value = Format(lista_final(i).time1, "dd/mm/yyyy hh:mm:ss.SSS")
                Worksheets("DADOS").Range("B" & a + 2).Value = lista_final(i).id_porta
                Worksheets("DADOS").Range("B" & a + 3).Value = lista_final(i).id_porta
                Worksheets("DADOS").Range("B" & a + 4).Value = lista_final(i).id_porta
                Worksheets("DADOS").Range("C" & a + 2).Value = lista_final(i).setor
                Worksheets("DADOS").Range("C" & a + 3).Value = lista_final(i).setor
                Worksheets("DADOS").Range("C" & a + 4).Value = lista_final(i).setor
                If lista_final(i).consumo_gas = 0 Then
                Worksheets("DADOS").Range("D" & a + 2).Value = "Água(L)"
                Else
                Worksheets("DADOS").Range("D" & a + 2).Value = "Água_Quente(L)"
                End If
                Worksheets("DADOS").Range("D" & a + 3).Value = "Gás"
                Worksheets("DADOS").Range("D" & a + 4).Value = "Eletricidade(KW)"
                Worksheets("DADOS").Range("E" & a + 2).Value = lista_final(i).consumo_agua
                Worksheets("DADOS").Range("E" & a + 3).Value = lista_final(i).consumo_gas
                Worksheets("DADOS").Range("E" & a + 4).Value = lista_final(i).consumo_ele
                Worksheets("DADOS").Range("F" & a + 2).Value = Format(lista_final(i).time2 - lista_final(i).time1, "hh:mm:ss.SSS")
                Worksheets("DADOS").Range("F" & a + 3).Value = Format(lista_final(i).time2 - lista_final(i).time1, "hh:mm:ss.SSS")
                Worksheets("DADOS").Range("F" & a + 4).Value = Format(lista_final(i).time2 - lista_final(i).time1, "hh:mm:ss.SSS")
                Columns("A:F").EntireColumn.AutoFit
                a = a + 3

        Next i

    End If

End Sub`
```

Comment: `Format` returns a `Variant/String`... you probably want to return a true `Date`.

Comment: @BigbBen Format (Format (final_list (i) .time1, "dd / mm / yyyy hh: mm: ss.SSS")) returns the value of the array and in this case it is reading time1 in the array which is a datatime (ex: 03/27/2020 21: 59: 30.00)
And this is correct through the debug I confirmed but when you write in the generated excel sheet "Dados" it presents the month exchanged with the day (ex: 01/04/2020 21: 59: 30,00) how can I correct this?
Because he is only presenting the month exchanged with the day when the day is less than 12

Comment: Right... because you are returning a `String` to the cell, so Excel is then interpreting/converting it to a date/time. This wouldn't happen if you wrote an actual `Date` to the cell.

Comment: @BigBen The problem is that it is a program and the user must just click on a button and then a new spreadsheet "Dados" appears with the data of the respective day that were saved in an array.

Comment: What is your default date format?  Whatever you enter into a cell, if it looks like a date, Excel will try to convert it to a date using your default format (and if it fails the value will remain as-entered). There's no confusing 03/27/2020, since there's no 27th month, but 01/04/2020 could either be April 1st or Jan 4th. Which of those dates it ends up as will depend on whether your default date format is mm/dd/yyyy or dd/mm/yyyy. As @BigBen says, *you should use an actual date, and format the cell with the format you want __before__ you insert that date*

Comment: @Tim Williams How do I check what is the standard data format in Excel?

Comment: https://excel.tips.net/T011574_Setting_a_Default_Date_Format.html

Comment: @TimWilliams I create a new spreadsheet how can I define the cell for that date format if the program creates a new spreadsheet?

Answer (score 0):

Whatever you enter into a cell, if it's a string which looks like a date (+/- time), Excel will try to convert it to a date using your default format (and if it fails the value will remain as-entered).

There's no confusing 03/27/2020, since there's no 27th month, but 01/04/2020 could either be April 1st or Jan 4th. Which of those dates it ends up as will depend on whether your default date format is mm/dd/yyyy or dd/mm/yyyy.

As @BigBen says, you should *use an actual date* (do not pass the date to `Format` before adding it to the sheet), and format the cell with the format you want *before* you insert that date:

```
Dim dt, dt2

dt = DateSerial(2020, 1, 4)    'Jan 4 2020
dt2 = DateSerial(2020, 1, 20)  'Jan 20 2020


With ActiveSheet

    .Range("A1").NumberFormat = "mm/dd/yyyy"
    .Range("A1").Value = dt  '>> 01/04/2020

    .Range("A2").NumberFormat = "dd/mm/yyyy"
    .Range("A2").Value = dt  '>> 04/01/2020

    .Range("B1").NumberFormat = "mm/dd/yyyy"
    .Range("B1").Value = dt2  '>> 01/20/2020

    .Range("B2").NumberFormat = "dd/mm/yyyy"
    .Range("B2").Value = dt2  '>> 20/01/2020

End With
```